# VBA True boolean condition not Respected

Tags: excel, vba, boolean

This is probably a really stupid question but I can't seem to find my way around it... I defined a global variable called safe_mode and is a boolean. In one of my subs I need to check its value and give it a new value accordingly. The code below will give you more information.

```
Private Sub Dev_Mode_Click()

Dim pass As String


If safe_mode = False Then

pass = InputBox("Password")
If pass <> "admin_rights" Then
    Sheets("Database").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    Sheets("NewFile").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    Sheets("LandingPage").Dev_Mode.Caption = "Admin"
    MsgBox ("Invalid Password")
    safe_mode = False
    MsgBox (safe_mode)
    Exit Sub
Else
    Sheets("Database").Visible = True
    Sheets("NewFile").Visible = True
    Sheets("LandingPage").Dev_Mode.Caption = "Log Off"
    safe_mode = True
    MsgBox (safe_mode)
    Exit Sub
End If
End If

If safe_mode = True Then

    Sheets("Database").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    Sheets("NewFile").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    safe_mode = False
    Sheets("LandingPage").Dev_Mode.Caption = "Admin"
    MsgBox ("Disconnect successful")
    MsgBox (safe_mode)
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

The value of safe_mode is correctly attributed. In other words I am getting true when in Admin mode and False when Logged Off. However, the If safe_mode = true condition is not respected. I am getting prompted for a password even when logging off which makes no sense, seeing as that code is only run when the safe_mode = false and the variable returns true in the MsgBox. Upon correct password entry while trying to log off the variable remains true. The only way to set it back to false is by missspelling the password. Any know their way around this?

Thanks!
D.

Comment: I suspect that the variable is not within scope. Use `Option Explicit` at the top of your module (the one containing your sub above) and check if the compiler yells.

Comment: That was the solution to my problem. Public variables can't be accessed from one module to another. They only work inside the same module for all the different subs within that module apparently. Thanks A.S.H !

Comment: `public safe_mode as Boolean` at the very top of a module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I think that Your variable is empty. It is not clear to me when You insert value to safe_mode, e. g. when You reopen Your workbook the safe_mode will be cleared, so maybe You need a sub which fires at workbook open and sets the value of safe_mode? Second option is to store value in a VBA hidden tab.

I've modified a little Your code so that You could test it (to check if safe_mode is not empty):

```
Public safe_mode As Boolean

Private Sub Dev_Mode_Click()

Dim pass As String

If IsEmpty(safe_mode) = True Then
   MsgBox("Cannot check if admin mode")
Else
   If (safe_mode = False) Then

   pass = InputBox("Password")
      If pass <> "admin_rights" Then
         Sheets("Database").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
         Sheets("NewFile").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
         Sheets("LandingPage").Dev_Mode.Caption = "Admin"
         MsgBox ("Invalid Password")
         safe_mode = False
         MsgBox (safe_mode)
         Exit Sub
      Else
         Sheets("Database").Visible = True
         Sheets("NewFile").Visible = True
         Sheets("LandingPage").Dev_Mode.Caption = "Log Off"
         safe_mode = True
         MsgBox (safe_mode)
         Exit Sub
      End If
   ElseIf (safe_mode = True) Then

      Sheets("Database").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
      Sheets("NewFile").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
      safe_mode = False
      Sheets("LandingPage").Dev_Mode.Caption = "Admin"
      MsgBox ("Disconnect successful")
      MsgBox (safe_mode)
      Exit Sub
   End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I managed to get my login system to work thanks to both your answer and ASH's. Got to remember to keep Option Ecplicit defined...

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Define variable as public at the top of the module. It will work only for the module. If it is defined in another module it won't be automatically imported.

Comment: No, if you declare it as `Public` it will be available in all the project. And a more important answer, **Always** use `Option Explicit`. It will save you a **lot lot** of time on the long run :)